# Encoding static member of class as JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, oop, static-members

I have the following piece of code.

```
class SomeClass
{
    public static $one = 1;
    private static $two = 2;
    public $three = 3;
    private $four = 4;
}

header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode(new SomeClass());
```

What I want to achieve is encode the public class property and member as a JSON object. My problem is that `json_encode()` ignores `public static $one = 1;` and the result will be:

```
{
    "three": ​3
}
```

Although I expect it to print the public static member as well, such as:

```
{
    "one": 1,
    "three": ​3
}
```

Can JSON encoding be done with static members in PHP?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859163/php-serialize-a-class-with-static-properties

Comment: @TobiasXy I think, the Reflection way is more elegant than your proposed (duplicate) solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> Static properties cannot be accessed through the object using the arrow operator ->.

That means ***no***

Nevertheless, I came up with the solution utilizing [Reflections](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php):

```
class SomeClass
{
    public static $one = 1;
    private static $two = 2;
    public $three = 3;
    private $four = 4;
}

$reflection = new ReflectionClass('SomeClass');
$instance = $reflection->newInstance();
$properties = $reflection->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);

$jsonArray = array();

foreach($properties as $property) {
    $jsonArray[$property->getName()] = $property->getValue($instance);
}

echo json_encode($jsonArray);
```

The result is

```
{"one":1,"three":3}
```

Answer (score 2):

In native implementation: NO.

In case you use Php v >= 5.4.0, you can use [JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.jsonserializable.php)

Here is example:

```
class myClass implements JsonSerializable
{
    private $_name = 'test_name';
    public $email = 'test@mail.com';
    public static $staticVar = 5;

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return get_class_vars(get_class($this));
    }
}

echo json_encode(new myClass());
```